# How garb all gets and posts (during HttpWebRequests & HttpWebResponses) in a simple windows application

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, capture, windows

How can i garb all gets and posts (during HttpWebRequests & HttpWebResponses) in a simple windows application using with c#?
as you know there is a specific extension for firefox named LiveHTTPHeaders.
i want something like that but not for a specific browser such as firefox.
i want it for all browsers and codes for a windows application!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler works with all browsers, it acts as a proxy so allows you capture and inspect all HTTP/S traffic.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: thanks for the answer / but i want to learn how does it do that? i want to write some codes in my own application to grab gets and posts.

Comment: Have a look at the API - http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/ - it's a .NET application so you should be able to inspect the code using ILSpy or dotPeek to see how it's done.

Comment: thanks for that link, hhhmm is it using proxy or not? mean is proxy necessary for using that assembly or not?